How to fix release in Jenkins after merging PR with incorrect Jira ticket? Error: No smart commit Jira issues found in the PR title for PR
Code stored in company GitHub. After I merged code by using pull request, which included incorrect Jira ticket in the title, deployment in Jenkins failed with the message:
ReleasePrePublishCheck
No smart commit Jira issues found in the PR title for PR #5

Note: It's been merged in default branch, which I can't delete (no permissions).
What I did:

I created separate branch "beta" from default by using command to get code before my PR:
git reset --hard 1234


It worked, I'm able to deploy this branch. But if I merge it to default (with another PR with proper ticket #), I'm still getting the same message.

I tried to fix message of that commit, by using command below and VIM editor:
git commit --fixup=amed:4567


Message changed, I can see in the history new commits with it. But if I do rebuild in Jenkins, I'm getting same error again.
How to fix it?

Well, the error doesn't look like an error. I'm sure it's something else.
